# Logging in with username/password (fetched from an API) in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm trying to handle the following situation in an Ansible playbook:

1. create a server via a cloud provider's API
2. store root credentials (username/password) from the API's response
3. use the root credentials to log in and place an SSH key
4. setup new users, disable root login, etc.

I can use `authorized_key` and `user` modules for step 4. I have a module (self-built) for step 1 and 2. How do I handle step 3 ? Are there any existing solutions for programmatically logging in with a username/password? I DO NOT want to give them via command line.

Basically I could build a module for this too. Ideally I'd like something similar to:

```
- task: setup SSH
  place_ssh_with_passwd:
    state: present
    key: /path/to/local/key
    path: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    user: "{{ server.username }}"
    password: "{{ server.password }}"
```

Comment: If everything fails, you can always simply run a local task and manually connect to the host with your credentials. Something like this: `- shell: sshpass -p 'password' scp /path/to/local/key root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys `.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `add_host` action to add the host to a new group and set ansible_ssh_host, ansible_ssh_user and ansible_ssh_pass with Jinja templates off your response from the cloud provider (see the example in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/add_host_module.html)). Then start a new play that targets the new group to do your key placement and whatever other setup tasks you want against the new host.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to accomplish this in the same play after server creation:

```
 - name: create server
   ...use module, create server and grap password from output...

 - name: add SSH key to server
   shell: "./scp_ssh_key.sh /path/to/key user@host:/path/ {{ passwd }}
```

Where the shell script would be something along the lines of:
https://gist.github.com/elnygren/965a6db4f3fd8e242e90

After this one could use Ansible's built in modules to setup users, other keys etc.